# Deshabitar JButton Java

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo problema con un JButton ya que idea es con 9 botones de se desactive el botón anteriormente pulsado. Pero el problema es que no se me ocurre como saber cual desactivar.He provado a ponerlos todos en un grupo pero eso no funciona. Alguien me puede arrojar un poco de luz. Dejo el código que llevo para que lo puedan ver.

```
       public class ButtonNumeros {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        create();

    }


    public static void create() {

        //s
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Radio Buttons");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.add(paint());

    }
    public static  JPanel paint() {

        int numero;
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton boton1, boton2, boton3,boton4, boton5, boton6,boton7, boton8, boton9;

        boton1 = new JButton("1");
        panel.add(boton1);
        boton2 = new JButton("2");
        panel.add(boton2);
        boton3 = new JButton("3");
        panel.add(boton3);
        boton4 = new JButton("4");
        panel.add(boton4);
        boton5 = new JButton("5");
        panel.add(boton5);
        boton6 = new JButton("6");
        panel.add(boton6);
        boton7 = new JButton("7");
        panel.add(boton7);
        boton8 = new JButton("8");
        panel.add(boton8);
        boton9 = new JButton("9");
        panel.add(boton9);

        boton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {




            }
        });







        return panel;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El siguiente código desactiva el último botón que se ha clickado. 
En el primer caso, **no te va a desactivar ninguno** porque no hay ninguno previamente pulsado. En tu código estás asignando el actionListener solamente al primer botón, por lo que sólo funcionará si primero clickas sobre éste:

```
boton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
// Y los demás botones?
```

Lo mejor es agrupar los botones y meterlos en una lista para añadir el actionListener a cada uno de ellos. Supongo que no lo estabas haciendo bien, porque sí se pueden agrupar. De hecho, puedes añadir el actionListener uno a uno, pero no veo el motivo.

Si quieres que se active de nuevo el botón, tendrás que recorrer el Array de botones y activarlos todos antes de desactivar el nuevo botón.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ButtonNumeros {

    private static JButton lastClicked = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        create();
    }

    public static void create() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Radio Buttons");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.add(paint());

    }

    public static void deactiveButton(JButton button) {
        if (lastClicked != null) {
            lastClicked.setEnabled(false);
        }
        lastClicked = button;
    }

    public static JPanel paint() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        List<JButton> buttonsList = new ArrayList<JButton>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
            JButton button = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
            panel.add(button);
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    deactiveButton(button);
                }
            });
        }
        return panel;
    }

}
```